# Given a cube in $\mathbb{R}^m$, what is the largest ball it contains? Given a ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$, what is the largest cube it contains?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

This question has be stumped completely - it is a question in C. Pugh's, *Real Analysis*.  Let me go over some definitions from within the text I'm referring to, and note that these definitions pertain to Euclidean space (where I dropped the boldface vector notation for simplicity - moreover, the book I'm using does this too, so this is for conventional purposes on my part also). This is a homework problem, and up front I thought to just answer the question flat out, but then, in class the other day, the professor mentioned that he wants us to prove our claim(s) on this problem.

***Definition:*** A **unit ball** in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is defined as $B^{m}=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}:|x|\leq 1\big\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$. The **unit sphere** is defined as $S^{m-1}=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}:|x|=1\big\}$.

***Definition:*** A **box** in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the Cartesian product of intervals $[a_{1},b_{1}]\times[a_{2},b_{2}]\times\cdots\times[a_{m},b_{m}]$. The **unit cube** in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is then defined as the box $[0,1]^{m}=[0,1]\times[0,1]\times\cdots\times[0,1]$.

***Definition:***  A set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is **convex** if for each pair of point $x,y\in E$ implies the straight line segment between $x$ and $y$ is also contained in $E$.

***Remark:*** The straight line determined by distinct point $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the set of all linear combinations $sx+ty$ where $s+t=1$ and the line segment is the set of all such linear combinations where $s,t\leq 1$.

***Definition:***  A **convex combination** is a linear combination $sx+ty$ with $s+t=1$ and $0\leq s,t\leq 1$.

---

These are all of the definitions given in the text after recapping vector addition, subtraction, etc., the dot product, the Triangle Inequality, The Euclidean distance between vectors, the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality, and the Triangle Inequality for distance all in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

**Preliminary Notes/Work:**  Now that you are on the same page as me, here's why I'm asking this problem. The book poses these questions, but the professor wants us to prove these results after making our respective claim(s). I started the problem by letting $[-a,a]^{m}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ be the given cube, and then I figured to claim that the ball $B_{0}^{m}:=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}:|x|\leq a\big\}$ is the largest ball contained in the cube (centered at the origin). From here, I figured to show $B^{m}\subset[-a,a]^{m}$ and then show that this ball is the largest by contradiction and/or to use the following:

**Definition** Let $S$ be a set with some property. A subset $H$ of $S$ is the **largest** with respect to the property if $H$ has the property and for any subset $K\subset S$ that has the property implies that $K\subset H$.

I also determined that both sets, the ball and the cube, are convex. And I started thinking that maybe the problem could be proved by showing that there exists a line segment in any ball with a radius larger than the one specified above does *not* lie in the given cube.  Any thoughts, recommendations, suggestions, etc. will be GREATLY appreciated!  Am I on the right track?  Is there another way to proceed? The problem is not marked as a difficult problem in the book, so I'm thinking there must be a way to do this without too much complexity? Keep in mind that we have not yet discussed topology, other than the definition of an arbitrary topology on a set. But I have some experience with metric spaces and defining a topology on them from independent study in the past.

Comment: and it's not difficult... suggest you get some graph paper and draw some good pictures of these comparisons in $\mathbb R^2$  http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph   Maybe see what you can do with drawings referring to $\mathbb R^3$ as well, perspective or something. Learning to draw, at least graph things, does help. i will check back in a few hours, plenty of others know how to do this as well, and many know the final answers

Comment: you seem at least part pit bull

Comment: @WillJagy I've already done that. That is how I came up with the ball to claim as the largest. I've proved convexity of it for practice and investigative purposes. I've worked out solutions in both $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, respectively. I'll look into them further, but that didn't get me anywhere as of now.

Comment: The definition of "largest" you have given is not appropriate to the question: taking $m=2$, there is no circle that can be inscribed in a square and that contains every circle that can be inscribed in that square (and similarly with "circle" and "square" interchanged). If the question in the book is exactly as you state it in your title, then you must be intended to interpret "largest" in terms of the radius of the balls or the edge length of the cubes (or something equivalent, such as volumes) - and it isn't a very well-stated question.

Comment: @RobArthan The question is exact, and I agree that the question isn't stated very well. I took the definition of a set being the largest with respect to a property from an abstract algebra text, as I'm stumped on how to prove this, and I thought that this definition might have some relevance. From your comment, it must not, but I'm still confused on how to proceed.

Comment: @WillJagy Regarding the pit bull comment...I hope your intentions were good processing that post, as I don't know what you mean by this.  The dog was a member of our family, he passed away at the age of 6, unexpectedly, and I thought you should know regarding any future posts in this respect - essentially this is something very personal to me.

Comment: Procore, sorry about your dog. I volunteered for a while (dog walking) at the city animal shelter. I don't any more, but I still walk around that pond and greet the dogs when other volunteers walk them. As usual, they have about half pit bulls, as people are uneasy about adopting them; to be specific, many of the other, more popular, breeds are readily sent to private shelters. Let's see; sorry if you felt some discomfort owing to my comment.

Comment: @WillJagy Absolutely no problem - I simply wasn't sure what you meant, but I see what you were trying to say...I work in a law firm, and I hear/read about people stereotyping these animals more than not.  In addition, I did want to mention that your comment was very helpful. I was in a stalemate when I posted the question, but I think I'm able to solve this problem now because of hard analysis of a ball/cube in two/three dimensions.  Thank yo so much for your help, and excuse me for getting uneasy - it was this past Spring I lost my dog, and I'm still trying to get over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: as discussed in the comments, we need to take "largest" to be measured by the edge length of the cubes or the radius of the balls, or equivalently by areas/volumes.

For cubes inside balls, look at the diagonal going from one corner to the opposite corner, e.g., from $(-1, -1, -1)$ to $(1, 1, 1)$ in the cube $[-1, 1]^3 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. This is the longest straight line segment contained in the cube and it will have to fit inside the containing ball. (So the solution will generalise the obvious way of inscribing a large square inside a circle.)

For balls inside cubes, note that the ball must meet a face of the cube and that then the diameter of the ball at the point of intersection must be orthogonal to the face. (So the solution will generalise the obvious way of inscribing a large circle inside a square.)

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't tell you how many times I kept redrawing a cube in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, seeing that the intersection of the boundaries of both sets were not empty, and then I kept thinking in this light on how to proceed (I kept coming back to this).  I see what you mean, and I will try and devise a solution for the first part of the problem...especially incorporating your suggestions and the definitions above (from the text).

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that it wants you to recognize that in fact, an open $cube$ is an open ball induced by the sup norm.

Namely, let $||x||$ be the euclidean norm and $||x||_{\infty}$ be the sup norm.

We then have $$||x||_{\infty} \leq ||x|| \leq \sqrt{m} \, ||x||_{\infty} .$$

Perhaps this can be a hint.

Comment: I've been meaning to answer this question. I've just been very busy, and I haven't been able to post an answer (or at least an answer I think is correct). I see where I was looking in the wrong place now, and, at some point in the future I will post an answer to this problem. Thanks for the hint, as it meshes well with my solution. I did another problem showing an ellipsoid $E=\big\{ (x,y,z) : \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} \leq 1\big\}$ is convex via the fact that it is a unit ball under a different dot product slightly similar to what you did above.